# Spring integration SFTP - issue with filters and number of messages emits

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I started using spring integration SFTP and I have some questions.

1. Filters not working. I have example configuration:

```java
Sftp.inboundAdapter(ftpFileSessionFactory())
                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
                .remoteDirectory(integrationProperties.getRemoteDirectory())
                .filter(sftpFileListFilter()) // doesn't work
                .patternFilter("*.xlsx") // doesn't work
```

And my ChainFileListFilter:

```java
private ChainFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> sftpFileListFilter() {
        ChainFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> chainFileListFilter = new ChainFileListFilter<>();
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(), "INT"));
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.xlsx"));
        return chainFileListFilter;
    }
```

If I understand correctly, only the XLSX file should be saved in the local directory. If yes it doesn't work with this configuration. Am I doing something wrong or misunderstood this?

2. How I can configure SFTP that each downloaded file emit message? I see in the doc two params `max-messages-per-poll` and `max-fetch-size`, but I don't know how to set it up so that every file emits a message. I would like to sync files once every 24 hours and produce batch job queue. Maybe there is a workaround?
3. Is there built-in filter which allow me fetch only files with changed content? The best solution would be to check the checksums of the files.

I will be grateful for your help and explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot combine `filter()` and `patternFilter()`. Only one of them can be used: the last one overrides whatever you used before. In other words: or `filter()` or `patternFilter()` - not both. By default the logic is like this:

```
public SftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec patternFilter(String pattern) {
    return filter(composeFilters(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter(pattern)));
}

private CompositeFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> composeFilters(FileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>
        fileListFilter) {
    CompositeFileListFilter<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> compositeFileListFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<>();
    compositeFileListFilter.addFilters(fileListFilter,
            new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(new SimpleMetadataStore(), "sftpMessageSource"));
    return compositeFileListFilter;
}
```

So, technically you don't need your custom one, if you don't use external persistent `MetadataStore`. But if you do, think about flipping `SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter` with `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter`. Since it is better to check for the pattern before storing the file into `MetadataStore`.

It is the fact that every synched remote file, passed those filters, is stored into local dir and the message for that local file is emitted immediately when the poller does a request.

The `maxFetchSize` plays the role when we load remote files into a local dir. The `maxMessagesPerPoll` is used from the poller, but those are already built from the local files. The message is emitted per local file, not as a batch for all of them. That's not what messaging is designed for.

Please, share more info what does not work with files. The `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` checks not only file name, but also `mtime` of the file. So, that it not about any checksum, but more last  modified timestamp of the file.

Comment: OK. I had mess in filters. I changed it and works well. I still not understand the poller. I am expecting that if SFTP download 4 files then immediately I have 4 messages. Next time if will be 2 files then I will expect 2 messages.

Comment: It depends on the `max-messages-per-poll`. But still: one message is produced after another: not all at the same time. But that can happen during the same polling cycle, that's true, if `max-messages-per-poll` is big enough. See source code of `AbstractPollingEndpoint` for better understanding

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much for your help. Big beer for you :)